# How to install php apd?

Tags: 14.04, php

How can I install [Advanced PHP Debugger](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.apd.php) in ubuntu?

I have tried `sudo pecl install apd`. It gives error `Cannot find config.m4.`. Is there any way I can install it via apt?

Answer (score 0):

This has been already answered [at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24690411/55075).

So basically try to reinstall your pecl extension following this [guide](http://www.mkfoster.com/2009/01/04/how-to-install-a-php-pecl-extensionmodule-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: I've edited this slightly to make the link work a little better, but I still recommend expanding it with a summary of the solution. Although theoretically this may answer the question as it stands, [it is considered preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I don't think that i can write better than that person.

Comment: isn't it a big hastle? Is there any easier solution? besides the solution in mentioned link pops up a lot of errors when installing on php 5.5.

Comment: I will search an another solution

Comment: Try to run this command `sudo apt-get install php5-dev` and reinstall apd

Comment: I already have that installed.